# Validate ISO Country Code in Mongoose Schema

Tags: mongoose-schema

I am trying to validate a country code (ISO 3166-1 alpha-2) in a Mongoose model.

e.g.

- `GB` for Great Britain
- `CY` for Cyprus

I couldn't find anything relevant in the Mongoose documentation.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the validator library.

```
const validator = require('validator');

country: {
    type: String, 
    validate: [ validator.isISO31661Alpha2, 'Invalid country'],
    trim: true,
    uppercase: true,
    required: [true, 'Country is required']
  }
```